# Interval of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I stumbled upon a Wikipedia article that claims:

Let all the roots of the polynomial $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$ be real. Then the roots lie in the interval given by:$$- \frac{a_{n-1}}{n} \pm \frac{n-1}{n} 
     \sqrt{a_{n-1}^2 - \frac{2n}{n-1} a_{n-2} }$$ How is this formula derived? For $n=2$, this is the quadratic formula. I read somewhere else that one has to use Cauchy-Schwarz. Can someone help me?

Comment: Presumably that Wikipedia article you found cites references?

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the roots be $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and notice $- a_{n-1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$ and $a_{n-2} = \sum\limits_{i<j} \alpha_i \alpha_j = (a_{n-1}^2 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2)/2$.

Therefore $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 = a_{n-1}^2-2a_{n-2}$.

Now let $x=\alpha_1$ and consider $x^2 + \sum\limits_{i=2}^n \alpha_i^2$ and note by convexity for fixed $x$ its minimum is $x^2 + (n-1)(\frac{-a_{n-1} - x}{n-1})^2$.

Hence we require $x^2 + (n-1)(\frac{-a_{n-1} - x}{n-1})^2 \leq a_{n-1}^2 - 2a_{n-2}$. [Solving](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2B%28n-1%29%28%28-a-x%29%2F%28n-1%29%29%5E2+%3D+a%5E2-2b+solve+for+x) this inequality yields the desired result (note it's just a quadratic polynomial in $x$).

Comment: Ahh, I see, you used Vieta's formula, right?

Comment: And how do you get $\sum\limits_{i<j} \alpha_i \alpha_j = (a_{n-1}^2 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2)/2$?

Comment: yes I used Vieta's formula, and that expresion consists of looking at $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i)^2$ and removing the squares.